# Problemas con FullCalendar en mi Modal, Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, modal, fullcalendar

Tengo un calendario de FullCalendar en mi proyecto de Laravel el cual al dar click a un input abre un modal donde esta ubicado el  calendario, al abrise el modal no me permite seleccionar un día si no hasta que le doy click a los botones para cambiar el mes, quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal o que debo de cambiar o agregar.

Código de Javascript:

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendario');

calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    showNonCurrentDates: true,
    locale: 'es',
    selectable: true,
    editable: true,
    eventColor: 'red',
    eventTextColor: '#fff',
    height: 'auto',
    buttonText: {
        today: 'Hoy',
    },
    eventOverlap: false,
    dateClick: function (info) {
        // Obtiene la fecha seleccionada en el calendario
        var fechaSeleccionada = info.dateStr;
        // Actualiza el valor del campo de entrada con la fecha seleccionada
        document.getElementById("fechaCita").value = fechaSeleccionada;
    },
    dayCellContent: function (info) {
        info.dayNumberText = info.dayNumberText.replace(/^0+/,
            ''); // Eliminar ceros a la izquierda
        return {
            html: '<span class="fc-day-number">' + info.dayNumberText + '</span>'
        };
    },
    dayCellDidMount: function (info) {
        var el = info.el;
        var num = el.querySelector('.fc-day-number');
        if (num) {
            num.style.color = '#000'; // Cambiar color del número a negro
        }
        el.style.backgroundColor = '#fff'; // Cambiar fondo del día a blanco
    },
    dayHeaderContent: function (info) {
        return {
            html: "<span style='color: black'>" + info.text + "</span>"
        };
    },
});

calendar.render();

fechaCita.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var modalEl = document.getElementById('calendarioModal');
    var modal = new bootstrap.Modal(modalEl);
    modal.show();
});
```

Código de HTML modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="calendarioModal" aria-labelledby="modal-fecha-label" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <br>
                    <div id="calendario"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Ya he intentado con todas las opciones de selección que da FullCalendar hasta cambiando el z-indice del modal pero nada parece funcionar